# How to avoid stroke around pgfplots fillbetween with shading?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, shading

If I shade an area with, e.g., pgfplots `\addplot[shade, top color=cyan] fill between ...`, the boundary of the shaded area has a very thin stroke around it.

**How do I avoid drawing any stroke around the boundary of the shaded area with pgfplots `fill between`?**

The stroke is almost imperceptible at the darker side, but it stands out at the lighter side, when rasterized by mupdf 1.22.1, by evince 43.0, and by firefox 115.

Examination of the SVG file generated by poppler 23.05.0 using `pdftocairo -svg` reveals a path toward the end of the file, which, if commented out or tweaked to say `fill:none` or `fill-opacity:0`, makes the boundary stroke go away:

```xml
<path style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;" d="..."/>
```

I assume examination of the PDF or DVI output of LaTeX would reveal something similar, but they aren't as amenable to examination by human.
Either way, I'm not sure how to go back to find where pgfplots generates this stroke.

- If I instead use `\addplot[fill=cyan] fill between ...`, the boundary stroke is gone.
- If I rasterize to png with ghostscript 10.01.2 using

  ```sh
  gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=png16m -r300 -sOutputFile=pgfplotsshadebetween.png pgfplotsshadebetween.pdf
  ```

  or with a higher resolution like `-r600` or `-r2400`, the boundary stroke is gone.
- If I rasterize to png with poppler 23.05.0 using `pdftocairo -png`, the boundary stroke is gone.

But these all either change the plot or rely on particular rasterizers, which are not the normal ones used to read PDF documents on screens.

---

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot[name path=rho, domain=0:1, opacity=0] {exp(-x)};
  \addplot[name path=zero, domain=0:1, opacity=0] {0};
  \addplot[shade, top color=cyan] fill between[of=rho and zero];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Screenshot from mupdf 1.22.1 (since none of the regular raster file output methods I could think of end up showing the stroke):

[image: screenshot of mupdf 1.22.1 viewing output of MWE]

Comment: Did you try adding `fill=none` to the relevant plot, like `\addplot[fill=none, shade, top color=cyan] fill between[of=rho and zero];`? By the way, `pgfplots`  already loads `tikz`, so there is no need to load `tikz` explicitlly

Comment: (No the original poster) I tested it out of curiosity, and the solution proposed by @JasperHabicht works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not extensively test this, but I'd assume that the reason for this stroke is a rendering issue that becomes more or less visible with scaling. I inspected the resulting PDF from your code and it seems that the path of the area is first filled black and then the gradient is clipped to fit inside it.

With `fill=none` added as option to the relevant `\addplot` command, the thin stroke should therefore go away and it should not be visible regardless of scaling or output to different formats.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[name path=rho, domain=0:1, opacity=0] {exp(-x)};
        \addplot[name path=zero, domain=0:1, opacity=0] {0};
        \addplot[fill=none, shade, top color=cyan] 
            fill between[of=rho and zero];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]