Tikz Gradient Fill Rectangle Without Border
I'm trying to draw a gradient filled rectangle that fades naturally into the page. Everything I read says \fill should not have a border yet I still get a faint border. How does one get rid of the faint gray lines on the left and right of my rectangle?
My code is pretty simnple:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\title{tempTikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} [font=\tiny\sffamily,%
                            arr/.style={-{Latex[scale=0.75]}},
                            ]
    \definecolor{c1}{HTML}{000000}
    \definecolor{c2}{HTML}{ffffff}

    \fill[left color=c2,right color=c2,middle color=c1] (0,3) rectangle ++(6,2);
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

This produces:


Try adding none as first option to the \fill command. Otherwise the shape is additionally filled black behind the gradient which can result in this effect depending on the PDF viewer. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/699629/47927

...your code is missing a \documentclass line ;-). I see no line with okular, and a thin line in evince at some zoom, so @JasperHabicht is right. Adding fill=none to the fill options seems to fix it at least for evince.

I was able to fix it by using a node instead:


Do not use \fill but \shade
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[left color=white, right color=white, middle color=black] (0,3) rectangle ++(6,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



The \fill command will always fill a path with black if not given a sensible color definition as option. It also does this if you define a gradient which will then essentially printed above the solid fill color.
Here, although you define how the gradient should look like, you don’t state how to fill the path. Therefore, the path is filled with the default solid color (which is black) and then the gradient is placed above this black fill. The black fill eventually flashes at the edges of the path when the PDF is displayed with some viewers.
To prevent this from happening, just add fill=none as first option to the \fill command to prevent the path from being filled with a solid color.
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\colorlet{c1}{black}
\colorlet{c2}{white}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[fill=none, left color=c2, right color=c2, middle color=c1] 
        (0,3) rectangle ++(6,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



If I use your suggestion I get:
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/none' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

Slight edit to your suggestion fixed the error and gave me what I wanted: \fill[fill=none, left color=c2, right color=c2, middle color=c1] (0,3) rectangle ++(6,2); (combined your suggestion with @Rmano
